# Create table, starting with digit in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, trigger.io

Can you give me suggestion to create table with starting with digits in postgresql.

Comment: You don't.  `"SQL identifiers and key words must begin with a letter (a-z, but also letters with diacritical marks and non-Latin letters) or an underscore (_)."` - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html

Comment: Actually, I can create table with double quotes e.g. "5258_emp"  but when i want to stored the value in that table.. it show error.

Comment: `"Actually, I can create table with double quotes e.g. "5258_emp""` - Sounds like you've answered your own question then.  As long as you always remember to enclose your identifiers then it should work.  Though it's still not the best idea.

Comment: You are right,  'As long as you always remember to enclose your identifiers then it should work.'  It can't be possible for  everytime to put double quotes in programming.

Comment: So then do you still have a question?  Seems that you have found your answer, as well as a user has posted an answer with an example below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use double quotes, eg:

```
t=# create table "42 Might be not The be$t idea" (i serial);
CREATE TABLE
t=# \d+ "42 Might be not The be$t idea"
                                             Table "public.42 Might be not The be$t idea"
 Column |  Type   |                                  Modifiers                                  | Storage | Stats target | Descript
ion
--------+---------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+--------------+---------
----
 i      | integer | not null default nextval('"42 Might be not The be$t idea_i_seq"'::regclass) | plain   |              |
```

Please look close at what it leads to. Generally using mixed case, special characters and starting relation from number is kept a bad practice. Despite the fact that Postgres understands and works with such relation names, you have  a risk to hit the bug with other software.

Without an experience you most probably shoot yourself in the foot. Eg `pg_dump -t "badName"` won't work. Bash will understand double quotes as own - and it is meant to work this way. So you have to specify `pg_dump -t '"badName"'` to find the table. And if you just fail to find a table you are lucky. Disaster is when you have `badname` and `Badname` in same schema.

The fact that it is doable does not mean you should jump into using it.

Comment: I deliberately created table with serial (so it would name sequence itself) to show how bad it looks.

Comment: you are right - I should have put warning. So I did.